# AWS resource tagging (python/boto3)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, tagging

Using `boto3`, almost every AWS resource has a different method for tagging [for examples, see 1].

Is there library that offer an unified programmatic interface for tagging any (or almost any) type of AWS resource?

[1] Examples:
`EC2` uses `create_tags()`, `delete_tags()`, `describe_tags()`
`S3` uses `delete_bucket_tagging()`, `get_bucket_tagging()`, `put_bucket_tagging()`
...

... different functions for all resources ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In boto3 you can use ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI method tag_resources(). Which is used to apply one or more tags to the specified list of resources.
Consider that not all resources can have tags and is limited to a specific region.
In the same way there is also a method to untag a list of resources: untag_resources()

---

Official documentation:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html#ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.Client.tag_resources

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html#ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.Client.untag_resources

Comment: Amazing! I'll try it out! Thanks!